# What is differentiable function with Lipschitz-continuous derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable with Lipschitz-continuous derivative.

Is this equivalent to the following?

All partial derivatives of $f$ are Lipschitz-continuous.

Or is one of the statements stronger?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: What is the definition that you have seen for a function to have Lipschitz-continuous derivative?

Comment: This is unfortunately not specified in the paper, is there a standard way of defining this?

Comment: I would say that a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has Lipschitz-continuous derivative if $\nabla f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz-continuous, and that seems to be equivalent to say that $\partial f/\partial x_i$ is Lipschitz-continuous for $i=1,\cdots,n$. I don't know if it is standard.

Comment: This is just a problem in terminology. What is "the derivative"? What are "the partial derivatives"? Depending on the answer to these questions, we can tackle your own question, which is:

 Is it true that "the derivative is Lipschitz continuous" is equivalent to "all partial derivatives are Lipschitz continuous"?

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuously differentiable and $\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the derivative, is a Lipschitz continuous function. The components of $\nabla f$ are all Lipschitz and are the partial derivatives of $f$.

The converseconverse: if all the partial derivatives are Lipschitz implies that they are continuous and you can use the total derivative theorem that tells you that you function $f$ is continuously differentiable and since its components are the partial derivatives then it is Lipschitz continuous.